# x is not a function ... what would you expect Object.create to do with a constructor

Tags: javascript

For this question, I'm not expecting a solution to solve something but would like to understand things better ..

Some quote from the specifications:

- Edition 5.1 ([Link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5))

  > §15.2.3.5 Object.create ( O [, Properties] )
  >
  > The create function creates a new object with a specified prototype. When the create function is called, the following steps are taken:
  >
  > 1. If Type(O) is not Object or Null throw a TypeError exception.
  > 2. Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in constructor with that name
  > 3. Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to O.
  > 4. If the argument Properties is present and not undefined, add own properties to obj as if by calling the standard built-in function Object.defineProperties with arguments obj and Properties.
  > 5. Return obj.
- Edition 6 - draft ([Link](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.create))

  > §19.1.3.2 Object.create ( O [, Properties] )
  >
  > The create function creates a new object with a specified prototype. When the create function is called, the following steps are taken:
  >
  > 1. If Type(O) is not Object or Null throw a TypeError exception.
  >
  >    1. Let obj be the result of the abstract operation ObjectCreate with argument O.
  >    2. If the argument Properties is present and not undefined, then
  >         a. Return the result of the abstract operation ObjectDefineProperties(obj, Properties).
  >    3. Return obj.

If I understood correctly, both of the specs allow the following code to be executed:

```
function F() {
}

var x=Object.create(F);

// a minimal test
alert(x.prototype.constructor===F); // true
alert(x instanceof Function) // true
alert(typeof x) // 'object'
```

Seems it created an object of a type derives from <sup>(sorry for the poor terminology .. )</sup> `Function` as I tested in FireFox, and so `x` is **non-invocable**:

```
x(); // x is not a function
```

I'm thinking about why doesn't it either disallow a constructor to be used as `O` or just create a valid constructor.

So I'm wondering what would you expect Object.create to do with a constructor?

Comment: I expect `Object.create` to ignore whether it is a constructor, as the algorithm doesn't need a callable object. Since it returns a simple `Object`, I also expect the result to be non-invocable.

Comment: What's the bounty for? Are there still outstanding questions? Would you like the answers to be more detailed?

Comment: It's difficult to choose one for marking as accepted answer when two have the same votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that won't work. What you have is an object that has `F` in its prototype chain; the fact that `F` is a function doesn't make `x` a function.

Only objects created via a function declaration or a function expression will have "Function" as their [[Class]], and a [[Call]] method, which makes it callable. Those are created according to the steps detailed on [section 13.2 of the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2).

The algorithm for `Object.create` does something different, as you can see on your quote. In your case, `x` will be a regular object with [[Class]] "Object" and no [[Call]] method. If you try `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`, you'll get `"[object Object]"`, where "Object" is the [[Class]] of `x`. `x instanceof Function` only returns `true` because the `Function` constructor is part of  the prototype chain of `x` (via `F`).

I'm not sure if any of that is going to be changed in ES6, but I suppose it won't.

Comment: `instanceof` doesn't have anything to do with [[Class]], please correct that sentence.

Comment: Very true @Bergi, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm wondering what would you expect Object.create to do with a constructor?

I would expect it to follow the spec of course…

> I'm thinking about why doesn't it either disallow a constructor to be used as O

Why should it? Every constructor function is an [object (§8.6)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6).

> … or just create a valid constructor.

The spec says it should create a plain object (as by `new Object`), whose [[prototype]] is set to O. Plain objects are no functions, they don't have a [[call]] or [[construct]] property. It also will have [[class]] `Object`, not `Function`.

> ```
> x.prototype.constructor===F // true
> x instanceof Function // true
> typeof x // 'object'
> ```
>
> Seems it created an object of a type derives from (sorry for the poor terminology .. ) Function

From `F`, actually. It does inherit the `.prototype` property from `F` (that's why your first test is `true`), and through `F` it also inherits from `Function.prototype` which makes it `instanceof Function`. Yet, it doesn't have a [[call]] property (it's not callable) so `typeof` does not yield `"function"`, but just `"object"`.

Comment: Good point. The reason of what I thought is, as it's a on-working spec and change frequently, why not a decision to make it either more useful or more strict to avoid an unusual object to be created ..

Comment: Nah, `Object.create` is quite well-defined and won't change its strict and minimalistic behaviour. Any "inheritance" solution for (constructor) functions would be specified under different terms in an extra function, to preserve the crucial backwards-compatibility.