# How extend a class from Function

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in javascript to create class which will create functions, not objects, just like Function class

```js
var realFunc = new Function();
typeof realFunc; // function

var myFunc = new MyFunction();
typeof myFunc; // object :(
```

I want to add some methods to function, but not to all of them. I don't want to add methods to each function object, better to add them to prototype of my class, isn't it?

Comment: Just have `myFunction` return a function, and call it as `var myFunc = myFunction()`.

Comment: Do you need methods from `function` that aren't present on `object`? If not, does it really matter which native object your class extends?

Comment: What do you mean by "class"? No, all javascript function objects do inherit directly from `Function.prototype`, and there is no (standard-conformant) way to change this.

Comment: You can't subclass Function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188458